# Does SDK supports JNI?

Tags: android, sdk, java-native-interface, android-ndk

Can i create a JNI application using SDK, or NDK needed for this purpose? I am confused whether SDK support java native interface or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a JNI application with the sdk, but simply using the NDK makes it less painful.